# Outlook add-in - detect if running in Outlook for Mac "New Look"?

Tags: office-addins, outlook-for-mac

Is there a way to detect in an Outlook add-in if it is running in the "New Look" view of Outlook for Mac?

We have found an issue where `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId` is not populated in "New Look" as mentioned in this issue - https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1400, but is populated in the "original" view.

We would like to display information that the add-in is not supported in the "New Look" view of Outlook for Mac.